# How do I export an XNA crossplateform project to Nintendo 3ds or Nintendo Switch?

Tags: c#, xna, nintendo

I would like to document my self a bit about 3ds and switch game creation. I know that modern game engine have builtin tools to export games to these platforms, but I could not find - in google research - an article or a website talking about this. Any time I searched "Xna Export to nintendo 3ds" I ended up with "getting 3ds max files into an XNA game" stuff.

I'll be highly grateful to anyone that could help me find a way to export my games to these,

Comment: Hi, the question that mine is a duplicate of, linked to the developper tools from nintendo. There, by downloading the NDI installer, you can get access to development tools such as ARM compilers and visual studio extensions for 3ds and Wii U builds. Note that a developer account seems to be free since I had been accepted for no fees.

Comment: As far I'm aware, XNA has ceased maintenance since 2014. Long before the Nintendo Switch was launched. XNA is also a Microsoft product, so if anything, it would support Xbox more likely than Nintendo. I'd rather recommend to try MonoGame (https://www.monogame.net/), since it's a similair enviroment as XNA, and is still supported to this day.